# Join and Calculate Average of column using LINQ to sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables

Video

- VideoId,
- VideoName,
- VideoUrl

Comment

- CommId,
- VideoId,
- CommentDesc,
- Rating

I want to join and get average rating for video using LINQ

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from video in Video join 
    comment in Comment on comment.VideoId equals video.VideoId;

Console.WriteLine("Average Rating: " + query
    .Where(i => i.VideoName = videoName)
    .Average(i => i.Rating));
```

Comment: If i want to get top 5 videos

how can i use order by Rating Desc and then take(5)

Comment: you could use query.GroupBy(i => i.VideoId, i => i, (ie, videoId) => new {VideoId = videoId, AverageRating = ie.Average(i => i.Rating)}).Take(5) the syntax might be a little off, I'm doing it from memory.